# Why is this query slow over certain ranges of data and fast over others?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, optimization

I have around 10 billion rows of points with coordinates `(x double, y double, z double)` in a MySQL table. I have created index indexes on columns `x`, `y`, and `z`, so that filtering by range is nice and snappy.

*Query Template:* (things in `{}` are replaced with actual values)

```
select id from points_table where
    x between {x-5} and {x+5} and
    y between {y-5} and {y+5} and
    z between {z-5} and {z+5};
```

Now, strangely this query **consistently** takes ~0.05 seconds for some points, and drastically large ~1.5 seconds for others, even though the number of results returned are approximately the same.

One of the examples is,

for `(x,y,z) = (1,5,-6)` query takes ~0.04 secs and fetches 45 results, but,

for `(x,y,z) = (-2,0,3)` query takes ~1.20 secs and fetches 38 results

This seems strange to me. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

EDIT: As requested here's explain on both queries,

```
explain select id from points_table where x between 1-5 and 1+5 and y between 5-5 and 5+5 and z between -6-5 and -6+5; 
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | tab          | type  | possible_keys     | key   | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                         |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | points_table | range | pnt_x,pnt_y,pnt_z | pnt_y | 9       | NULL | 18748 | Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+


explain select id from points_table where x between -2-5 and -2+5 and y between 0-5 and 0+5 and z between 3-5 and 3+5; 
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | tab          | type  | possible_keys     | key   | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                         |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | points_table | range | pnt_x,pnt_y,pnt_z | pnt_y | 9       | NULL | 235748 | Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------+-------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I think only index for `y` is being used, also there's a lot of difference in number of rows, which would explain the time gap.

But now my question is,

how do I get mysql to use all indexes? they are there for a reason.

**EDIT:**

So I created a composite key (x, y, z) and MySQL seems to prefer it while doing range filters, also queries take consistently less time.

Comment: Please show the execution plan. MySQL probably does not use more than a single index, and the data skew could be unfortunate. Can you post the counts among each of the three dimensions separately (`where x between 1-5 and 1+5` and so on).

Comment: And additionally to execution plan and statistics - the table schema

Comment: @Thilo added explain output to the question

Comment: `18748` vs `235748` --- it's an order of magnitude difference to scan over.

Comment: But how do I get mysql to use all indexes, they are there for a reason...

Comment: You cannot for range comparisons. If the ranges are fixed - you may denormalize data by putting the range id and comparing with strict equality. That way you could use a composite index. Or it would worth trying to split this into a query with 2 `INNER JOIN`s and praying that mysql can optimize it better.

Comment: @zerkms tested your suggestion about 2 `INNER JOIN`s, but mysql still uses only one index for range lookup, `JOIN ON x BETWEEN...` is internally treated as a `WHERE` clause

Comment: You might try to use a composite index. But the order of fields matters, put the most restrictive field first (if there is any clear difference in that regard).

Comment: @Thilo for range comparisons B-Tree based indexes will only compare the first part

Comment: @Thilo my purpose of running these queries is to create an index. it's naive, just a table storing list of point ids, and density, for each 10x10x10 box in x,y,z space. I thought this query would run faster if I had indexes on all 3 columns. Well, lookups would be faster once i have this index... in about 4 hrs (processing... 35689 of 64000, eta: 3.89 hrs)  :-\

Comment: @zerkms I created a composite key (x, y, z) and MySQL seems to prefer it while doing range filters, also queries take consistently less time, `Extra` from `EXPLAIN` reads `Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` I guess this is a good thing

Comment: @zerkms: Why is that? MySQL limitation? It should be able to use all columns (in index order). And Optimus last comment seems to support that.

Comment: @Thilo http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/range-optimization.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mrr-optimization.html yep, mysql uses MRR in this case, and honestly I forgot that mysql has such kind of optimization. But it's still kind of exception not the rule for B-Trees. Btw, from the last comment we see that mysql DISABLES MRR, which means it makes a dummy scan instead

Comment: @zerkms: that first link you gave states that all columns in a multi-key index are used if possible in the range scan. There is even an example with three columns that is very close to the current case. Pretty straightforward case of a range scan.

Comment: @Thilo: could you please point to what you're talking about? I don't see anything in the first link that uses multi-column index with all predicates specified as ranges (which also states that the whole index is going to be used).

Comment: @zerkms: Okay, I may have misread that. Seems like it does not consider extra columns after the first range (only doing that if the prefix columns use an equality condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query plan will tell you which index is really being used -- but for discussion purposes, lets assume Y is always used.

You are likely seeing a situation similar to where Index X selects 18,748 rows and the X and Z ranges filter out all but 45 rows, but for the 2nd query Index X selects 235,748 rows and the X and Z ranges filter the results to 38 rows.

Same query, same execution plans not counting the I/O amounts, but lots more data being processed in the 2nd query to get a similar result in terms of total rows.

UPDATED this answer with actual query plan info as suggested by zerkms.

Comment: Just a ping in case if you're not on the page: OP has updated the question so it's possible to update the answer with actual numbers :-)